# How to configure email autoconfiguration for a domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, outlook, dns-server

Outlook and a number of other email clients now feature autodiscovery of mail server settings and it bugs me that I don't have this set up for our domains, but I'm not sure how to do it and a quick google hasn't turned up anything. I presume it's done with some kind of SRV record in DNS - is this correct and if so what's the correct format?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I am sorry I might be late to the party here. If you are still looking for a solution, I spent a weekend figuring out how to provide Auto Configuration (autodiscover what Outlook 2010 calls it) for most popular email clients including iOS.

I wrote it all down in a blog post here: http://moens.ch/2012/05/31/providing-email-client-autoconfiguration-information/ (also [available via archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150817115525/http://moens.ch:80/2012/05/31/providing-email-client-autoconfiguration-information/))

Outlook 2010 actually does a combination of DNS lookup and XML config. It first does a SRV lookup for `_autodiscover._tcp.<yourdomain>` and then does an xml POST request to your autodiscover url and expects an XML response. My post contains samples of the XML response and a link to the full autodiscover xml Response spec on MS technet.

In short: You *can* provide full autodiscover functionality to your users even without Exchange server.

Comment: Your blog is gone, is this post you mention available somewhere else?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20120828065248/http://moens.ch/2012/05/31/providing-email-client-autoconfiguration-information/

Comment: Here's an archive link that has some better formatting: https://web.archive.org/web/20150817115525/http://moens.ch:80/2012/05/31/providing-email-client-autoconfiguration-information/

Answer (score 13):

[RFC 6186](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6186) describes how to use SRV records for e-mail services. Summary:

- SRV records like `_submission._tcp SRV 0 1 587 mail.example.com.` and `_pop3`, `_pop3s`, `_imap`, `_imaps`. (Last number is the port number.)
- When offering both IMAP and POP, use the first number to show which is preferred (lower is preferable).

I don't know which MUA's already implement this. Maybe KMail. Thunderbird [not yet](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird:Autoconfiguration)?

Comment: I think android does something like this...

Comment: android doesn't use SRV, just autodiscover.xml: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=45380

Comment: Claws Mail implements this (since 3.10, IIRC)

Comment: kmail does not seem to, unless I have done something wrong I filed a [bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=441193)

Answer (score 2):

So far as I know, the (Outlook) feature requires Exchange 2007 or later.

Comment: I don't think it's an exchange feature, because you don't have to put in the address of your mail server...

Comment: Apologies - just found this http://exchangeexchange.com/forums/t/551.aspx - looks like it does use dns but is exchange specific...

Comment: No worries, it wouldn't be the first time Microsoft had commandeered a bit of terminology and implemented it in a way that stomps all over someone else's standard.  :/

Comment: Yep, and again not for the first time it's one of those things that you wish the internet would manage to sort out a single standard for, but it never happens :/